Call to printf missing _img__ references
I have installed CygWin in a fairly minimal installation that has gcc.  When I write a program
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  printf("asdf");
  return 0;
}

and compile it via gcc a.cpp -L/cygdrive/c/windows/system32, I get the following error:
ld: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `_imp__LoadLibraryA@4'
ld: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_imp__GetProcAddress@8'
ld: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `_imp__FreeLibrary@4'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

in addition to a few warnings of similar text.  I had a similar error earlier, and found that the library which is being called (kernel32.dll) is located in the C:\Windows\System32 folder; hence I added the path to make that error go away.  Is there a library that is missing from the installation / path, which would have the _imp__ functionality?
p.s., the .s file compiles without any problems.
p.p.s. I tried the mingw32 C compiler, and instead of 3 messages it returned about 20.  Most of them deal with _imp__, but there are also a few such as from __acrt_iob_func and _set_invalid_parameter_handler.  Also, it has names of functions where these errors occur, such as mark_section_writeable or matherr.  All in the mingw directory, obviously.
Update: I ran the compile command via strace.  At the bottom are the relevant lines of the output.  It looks like it was trying to create the .exe file (namely, the fstat (\??\D:\home\a.exe, 0x11CC6D0)); however, at the end it ended up deleting it.  Any ideas how to interpret this information?
63 1978789 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::read: returning 65536, binary mode
51 1978840 [main] ld 5123 read: 65536 = read(9, 0x80125B20, 65536)
2449 1981289 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 524288
53 1981342 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 524288 = lseek(9, 524288, 0)
49 1981391 [main] ld 5123 read: read(9, 0x80125B20, 65536) blocking
66 1981457 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::read: returning 65536, binary mode
55 1981512 [main] ld 5123 read: 65536 = read(9, 0x80125B20, 65536)
1268 1982780 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 1376256
53 1982833 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 1376256 = lseek(9, 1376256, 0)
48 1982881 [main] ld 5123 read: read(9, 0x80125B20, 65536) blocking
64 1982945 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::read: returning 65536, binary mode
51 1982996 [main] ld 5123 read: 65536 = read(9, 0x80125B20, 65536)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld 6258 1989254 [main] ld 5123 write: 64 = write(2, 0x612EC31C, 64)
: warning: resolving   260 1989514 [main] ld 5123 write: 21 = write(2, 0x53F29A, 21)
__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4  259 1989773 [main] ld 5123 write: 25 = write(2, 0x8009955E, 25)
 by linking to   254 1990027 [main] ld 5123 write: 15 = write(2, 0x53F2B1, 15)
__imp__GetModuleHandleA  255 1990282 [main] ld 5123 write: 23 = write(2, 0x803150DE, 23)

255 1990537 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53F2C2, 1)
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
1039 1991576 [main] ld 5123 write: 53 = write(2, 0x53F2C4, 53)
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
1140 1992716 [main] ld 5123 write: 52 = write(2, 0x53F2FC, 52)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld 1271 1993987 [main] ld 5123 write: 64 = write(2, 0x612EC31C, 64)
: warning: resolving   256 1994243 [main] ld 5123 write: 21 = write(2, 0x53F29A, 21)
_GetModuleHandleA@4  255 1994498 [main] ld 5123 write: 19 = write(2, 0x801C6764, 19)
 by linking to   257 1994755 [main] ld 5123 write: 15 = write(2, 0x53F2B1, 15)
_GetModuleHandleA  256 1995011 [main] ld 5123 write: 17 = write(2, 0x803150CC, 17)

255 1995266 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53F2C2, 1)
23005 2018271 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::fstat_helper: 0 = fstat (\??\D:\home\a.exe, 0x11CC6D0) st_size=0, st_mode=0100644, st_ino=844424930571529st_atim=66BBA095.1545DFC0 st_ctim=66BBA095.1545DFC0 st_mtim=66BBA095.1545DFC0 st_birthtim=66BBA095.15369D80
60 2018331 [main] ld 5123 fstat64: 0 = fstat(3, 0x11CC6D0)
248 2018579 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 48639
53 2018632 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 48639 = lseek(3, 48639, 0)
1792 2020424 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 487)
253 2020677 [main] ld 5123 write: 487 = write(3, 0x80402380, 487)
133 2020810 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 1024
52 2020862 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 1024 = lseek(3, 1024, 0)
1105 2021967 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 144)
83 2022050 [main] ld 5123 write: 144 = write(3, 0x80402380, 144)
131 2022181 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 7680
52 2022233 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 7680 = lseek(3, 7680, 0)
1071 2023304 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 4805)
77 2023381 [main] ld 5123 write: 4805 = write(3, 0x80402380, 4805)
141 2023522 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 35328
57 2023579 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 35328 = lseek(3, 35328, 0)
946 2024525 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 541)
61 2024586 [main] ld 5123 write: 541 = write(3, 0x80402380, 541)
131 2024717 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 7168
52 2024769 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 7168 = lseek(3, 7168, 0)
1100 2025869 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 32)
58 2025927 [main] ld 5123 write: 32 = write(3, 0x80402380, 32)
130 2026057 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 38912
52 2026109 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 38912 = lseek(3, 38912, 0)
762 2026871 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 163)
59 2026930 [main] ld 5123 write: 163 = write(3, 0x80402380, 163)
130 2027060 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 41472
52 2027112 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 41472 = lseek(3, 41472, 0)
594 2027706 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 14)
59 2027765 [main] ld 5123 write: 14 = write(3, 0x80402380, 14)
129 2027894 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 41984
57 2027951 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 41984 = lseek(3, 41984, 0)
595 2028546 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 737)
61 2028607 [main] ld 5123 write: 737 = write(3, 0x80402380, 737)
130 2028737 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 3656
52 2028789 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 3656 = lseek(3, 3656, 0)
945 2029734 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 52)
59 2029793 [main] ld 5123 write: 52 = write(3, 0x80402380, 52)
129 2029922 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 5120
52 2029974 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 5120 = lseek(3, 5120, 0)
641 2030615 [main] ld 5123 write: write(3, 0x80402380, 56)
58 2030673 [main] ld 5123 write: 56 = write(3, 0x80402380, 56)
130 2030803 [main] ld 5123 fhandler_base::lseek: setting file pointer to 49126
52 2030855 [main] ld 5123 lseek64: 49126 = lseek(3, 49126, 0)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld 1773 2032628 [main] ld 5123 write: 64 = write(2, 0x612EC31C, 64)
:   255 2032883 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x53B990, 2)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o  618 2033501 [main] ld 5123 write: 41 = write(2, 0x800B0E98, 41)
:  256 2033757 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA43, 1)
cygming-crtbeg  270 2034027 [main] ld 5123 write: 14 = write(2, 0x800C86C8, 14)
:  100 2034127 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA47, 1)
(  254 2034381 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA4D, 1)
.text  257 2034638 [main] ld 5123 write: 5 = write(2, 0x800B1248, 5)
+0x  274 2034912 [main] ld 5123 write: 3 = write(2, 0x53CA51, 3)
2c  262 2035174 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x11CC4B6, 2)
)  253 2035427 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA56, 1)
: undefined reference to `  334 2035761 [main] ld 5123 write: 26 = write(2, 0x53B994, 26)
_imp__LoadLibraryA@4  452 2036213 [main] ld 5123 write: 20 = write(2, 0x80225AE8, 20)
'
293 2036506 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x53B9B1, 2)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld 1502 2038008 [main] ld 5123 write: 64 = write(2, 0x612EC31C, 64)
:   337 2038345 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x53B990, 2)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o  302 2038647 [main] ld 5123 write: 41 = write(2, 0x800B0E98, 41)
:  322 2038969 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA43, 1)
cygming-crtbeg  297 2039266 [main] ld 5123 write: 14 = write(2, 0x800C86C8, 14)
:  102 2039368 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA47, 1)
(  294 2039662 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA4D, 1)
.text  278 2039940 [main] ld 5123 write: 5 = write(2, 0x800B1248, 5)
+0x  280 2040220 [main] ld 5123 write: 3 = write(2, 0x53CA51, 3)
32  301 2040521 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x11CC4B6, 2)
)  297 2040818 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA56, 1)
: undefined reference to `  367 2041185 [main] ld 5123 write: 26 = write(2, 0x53B994, 26)
_imp__GetProcAddress@8  475 2041660 [main] ld 5123 write: 22 = write(2, 0x80225AE8, 22)
'
295 2041955 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x53B9B1, 2)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld 1114 2043069 [main] ld 5123 write: 64 = write(2, 0x612EC31C, 64)
:   270 2043339 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x53B990, 2)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/11/crtbegin.o  259 2043598 [main] ld 5123 write: 41 = write(2, 0x800B0E98, 41)
:  255 2043853 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA43, 1)
cygming-crtbeg  255 2044108 [main] ld 5123 write: 14 = write(2, 0x800C86C8, 14)
:  100 2044208 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA47, 1)
(  255 2044463 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA4D, 1)
.text  256 2044719 [main] ld 5123 write: 5 = write(2, 0x800B1248, 5)
+0x  255 2044974 [main] ld 5123 write: 3 = write(2, 0x53CA51, 3)
d6  256 2045230 [main] ld 5123 write: 2 = write(2, 0x11CC4B6, 2)
)  254 2045484 [main] ld 5123 write: 1 = write(2, 0x53CA56, 1)
: undefined reference to `  333 2045817 [main] ld 5123 write: 26 = write(2, 0x53B994, 26)
_imp__FreeLibrary@4  448 2046265 [main] ld 5123 write: 19 = write(2, 0x80225AE8, 19)


Try removing the -L option completely.

@DougHenderson That's what I did in the beginning; but it told me that kernel32.dll could not be found.  I wonder if there is another kernel32.dll that it might be requiring?  I also updated the post with more debugging information.

@DougHenderson Apparently cygwin_base was missing (!).  I am surprised this entire time, not a single warning message about it; just noticed it as I was browsing the "full" list of packages.  Once I installed cygwin_base, then removing the -L option did the trick.

Make sure you are using the latest Cygwin setup.exe downloaded from cygwin.com. Other methods of installing Cygwin packages is not supported.
